# How to disable "WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException"

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

i'm trying to get started with simple java ee application, using following components: JSF 2.0, JPA EclipseLink, Glasshfish 3.

Here is some snippets, backing bean:

```
@Inject
private ProductsFacade model;    
public void saveRow(Products p) {
        model.edit(p);
}
```

ProductsFacade:

```
@Stateless
public class ProductsFacade extends AbstractFacade<Products> {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    public void edit(Products entity) {
        em.merge(entity);
    }
    ....
```

Products is a entity bean with bean validation annotations.

Now when user fills form incorrectly 'model.edit' throws EjbException, i handle it
with catch, so `saveRow` backing bean method now look not so concise:

```
public void saveRow(Products p) {
    try {
        model.edit(p);
    } catch (EJBException e) {
        if(e.getCause().getClass().getName().equals("javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException")) {
            handleConstraintViolation((ConstraintViolationException)e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

And still glassfish log filled with  "WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException" and long traces.
I have some questions:

1. How correct is my setup ? I know that jsf should handle BeanValidation, but it does not in my case.
2. How to disable `EJBException` warnings, so server log will not be polluted
3. Is there better way to handle EjbException ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EJBException`s triggers rollback of the current JTA transaction whether you catch them or not. The call to `ProductsFacade#edit()` starts a transaction (unless one is propagated to it, which doesn't seem to be the case here) since it is a call "from outside" into a SessionBean. If you don't want your transaction to rollback in these scenarios you have to validate the user/client input somehow somewhere before giving the broken `Entity` to the `EntityManager`.

There are several quirks and stuff to do here to avoid this situation. For example you can have the `ProductsFacade` handle transactions: `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)`, that would take away a big part of the point of using EJBs though. I do think this default behaviour is as it should be. If you don't want the Rollback in your log you can configure your logging level/etc - but I do think that EJB layered transactional rollbacks belongs in the log, it does definitely during development.